# Badge icons not showing on chat profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, chat, design

I just noticed that badge icons for my chat profile don't show up anymore:

[image: Badges in chat profile]

[Unihedro could not repro](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2955597#2955597), but [Fundamental could](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2955611#2955611).

Is this a bug, or is it just us?

I'm using Firefox 35.0 on Windows 7.

Note, this is also impacting oneboxing of profiles in chat too:

[image]

Comment: CSS bug hence design tag is due. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chat uses Stack Overflow's sprite sheet for the badge images, and the Stack Overflow design refresh moved a few things around in that image file; those changes weren't reflected in the chat CSS yet.

Fixed now.

As to the the question of why it worked for some people and not for others: that may have depended on what CDN edge node you're hitting and how hard you refreshed, so it's not unexpected that it looked different for different people.

Answer (score 1):

<del>As mentioned, I could not reproduce this. Here were the sprites in the CSS class that holds the badges:</del>

[image: sprites]

Upon refreshing the stylesheet per [Fundamental](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259867/fundamental)'s advice, it now broke for me too.

Comment: This is not the [sprites file](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=272483674ecb) that I  see used on that page.

Comment: @Fundamental Weird, by clicking into your link, I see an exact same version as that in my console. Maybe... It's caching!

Comment: What if you click my link and refresh?

Comment: @Fundamental ... Now it broke.