# Super collider drop downs have stopped working on chat.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

...at least in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer, anyway.

If you browse to chat.stackexchange.com while logged in you get your StackExchange/Inbox/Activity menu icons but clicking them doesn't result in a menu. This still seems to be working on actual sites but not on chat.

Comment: Broken in Firefox too.

Comment: Wild guess... maybe [this fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247586/152859) broke the super collider? :/

Comment: IE also broken and also broken on http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cleaned up some top bar-related code earlier; unfortunately this resulted in the top bar menus not being visible when some initialization code ran too early (as a result of said clean-up).

Fixed now, thanks.